# Python in Google Colaboratory - How to create, write and read files in google drive

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, google-colaboratory

I tried using the code below to create a file but it didn't work when I tried to search it in my drive. Here is the link to my code if you need to see the full thing. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1N436bntHOf146ZMGVBeSh5EXBuYAjvQY?usp=sharing

Here is the code I used to create and write a file.

```
output = open("sequences.fasta", "w")
output.writelines('>' + firstheader + '\n' + seq1 + '\n')
output.writelines('>' + secondheader + '\n' + seq2.upper() + '\n')
output.writelines('>' + thirdheader + '\n' + seq3.replace('-', '') + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**

You'll need to mount your google drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
```

I would advise you to go to the default repository for the notebooks:

```
!cd '/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/'
```

**Actual Solution**

When you are done you have to flush and unmount to see the changes in Gdrive

```
drive.flush_and_unmount()
```

**Just a download**

Or you can use directly `files` to download it:

```
from google.colab import files
files.download('sequences.fasta')
```